# Python on Raspberry Pi 4 (Buster) - reduce delay before audio sounds

Tags: python, audio, latency

I have a PIN entry screen written in Python.

When a key is pressed I play a beep sound.

The sound file:
key_beep = ['play', '/home/pi/SiChess/Sounds/key_beep.mp3']

My play command:
subprocess.Popen(key_beep, shell=False, stdout = subprocess.DEVNULL)

The problem is the short delay between the keypress and the beep sounding. I expect this is due to loading the 'play' executable for each keypress.

I did try PyGame, but only succeeded in breaking my Python environment, and my reading gives me little confidence that it will solve it anyway.

Apart from using 'play' and trying PyGame I tried adding a long timeout to load-module module-suspend-on-idle in /etc/pulse/default.pa, but that made no difference to this issue.

Is there a way to have something memory resident that can I feed with sound files?

Any other suggestions?